# Get Nintex Holidays from SSIS

Tags: sharepoint

SharePoint \ Nintex

Is it possible to get nintex holiday list into SSIS package?

SharePoint lists work nicely as OData listdata.svc sources in the package. But what about Nintex service lists, can it be accessed thru webservices?

Answer (score 0):

When using Nintex, you can use the **call web service** action or the **web service request** action to perform a standard HTTP web service call.  You can use build strings to prep the call and also parse the response via collection or dictionary variables and get that output parse via the XML actions.